# autofocus="true" is not working in google chrome when contained in and <iframe> after google chrome upgrade to 79.0.3945

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, autofocus

I have a web application that was running fine for the last five years till the upgrade of Google Chrome to the latest version 79.0.3945. All forms are loaded in an iframe and focus is set on the first field of the form using `autofocus="true"`. But after the upgrade of Google Chrome, the first field of the form is not receiving focus. Have anyone any clue about it or some solution. Please note that if the form is not loaded in an `<iframe>`, `autofocus="true"` works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like yet another bug introduced into Chromium! You can check the issues page to find and follow the issue or report it yourself, under...

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list

And until a fix is found you may want to use a little javascript for a temp fix like this...

```
 Your_Frame_ID.contentWindow.document.forms[0].elements[0].focus();
```

Comment: Though I didn't try to find any solution of this problem any further, because it was working fine in OPERA, but now it seems that OPERA is copying CHROME because the same problem has today emerged in OPERA as well.

Comment: googling found this ``Issue 1046357: autofocus does not work when URL contains fragment in Chrome 79``